# How to set URL alias as link in a Drupal view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created the taxonomy and add some item under the taxonomy. Then it is define to the content type and add some content under taxonomy.
I have shown the taxonomy title to my view and content under taxonomy I shown to other page.

I am facing issue to how to set link on content title.
[image]

[image]

How to replace link with

```
http://localhost/drupal7/node/19
```

to

```
http://localhost/drupal7/artist-works/Robert-Boynes/Infinite-Red
```

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that you have Pathauto installed and all nodes already have an alias do the following:

1. In your view add a new field "Content: Path".
2. Hide that field.
3. Ensure that you place this field BEFORE your title field (reorder).

Now the alias will be available as token to build the link.

Comment: created the Content:nid and align at top in field ,and set artist-work/['title'],its work for me .

Comment: @ManmeetKhurana, if you add link like `node/[nid]` it'll also work and will auto generate alias's as you want. It works for me though.

Comment: Hello Leymannx , Will you assist on this problem https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262569/autocomplete-not-working-for-specific-content-type-in-drupal-8?noredirect=1#comment321648_262569